# Add prebuilt/standalone static library to Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, java-native-interface

I've been scouring things for an aswer to this question, but everybody seems to have old or outdated advice.  I'm looking for something that applies to Android Studio 2.3.3.

I had a static library that I'm using: libopus.a  The standalone toolchain builds it just fine with a fairly normal. "./configure; make" dance.

Once I have it, though, I can't seem to find out either where to put it or how to link it using the normal Gradle/CMakeLists.txt mechanisms.

I'm trying to call the library from inside my JNI code.  I'm presuming that I need to put it in some "magic" place in my source tree, tell Gradle where it is, and adjust link flags in the CMakeLists.txt to find it.  I just can't seem to get all the pieces together simultaneously.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

This link explains how :
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

Maybe this link could help you, it has an example with a static and a shared lib.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs